# Terraform config: strconv.ParseInt: parsing invalid syntax error

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am experiencing a syntax error when I tried to run this config, this happened after an automatic update of the AWS provider.

```
variable "availability_zone" {
  default = "*****"
}

variable "vpc_id" {
  default = "*******"
}

variable "subnet_count" {
  default = "1"
}

data "aws_vpc" "env" {
  id = "${var.vpc_id}"
}

data "external" "net" {
  program = ["/atf/bin/atf-subnet-reservation-alloc"]

  query = {
    subnet_count = "${var.subnet_count}"
    vpc_id = "${var.vpc_id}"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "net" {
  count             = "${var.subnet_count}"
  vpc_id            = "${data.aws_vpc.env.id}"
  availability_zone = "${var.availability_zone}"
  cidr_block        = "${cidrsubnet(data.aws_vpc.env.cidr_block, 8, element(split(",",data.external.net.result.subnets),count.index))}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = "true"

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when = "destroy"
    command = "/atf/bin/atf-subnet-reservation-free ${self.cidr_block}"
    on_failure = "continue"
  }
}
```

Crash output:

> module.aws_env.aws_subnet.net: 1 error(s) occurred: Mon Oct 22
>   14:05:15 2018:: * module.aws_env.aws_subnet.net:
>   __builtin_StringToInt: strconv.ParseInt: parsing "": invalid syntax in: Mon Oct 22 14:05:15 2018::
>   ${cidrsubnet(data.aws_vpc.env.cidr_block, 8,
>   element(split(",",data.external.net.result.subnets),count.index))}

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's because you updated the AWS provider? Can you run it against multiple versions of the provider to isolate which version broke this for you? What does the output of your external data source command give you?

Comment: Which version of `aws provider` worked for you and which version you see this broken?